# Rails param is missing or the value is empty: order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to call a controller action in my rails application like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("paypal.gif", :margin => "0" ), {:controller => :orders, :action => :payMovie, :id => @movie.id}, :class=>"pull-right btn btn-default" %>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class OrdersController < ActionController::Base

  ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true
  layout "application"
  skip_before_action :user_logged_in

  #Movie-Bestellung erstellen
  def payMovie
    @order = OrderMovie.new
    @order.user << User.find(session[:user_id])
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]

    puts "sssssssssssss"
    puts @movie.inspect

    @order.price = @movie.movieprice
    @order.currency = @movie.currency
    @order.movie << @movie
    if @order.save
      flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

end
```

But then I got this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in OrdersController#payMovie
param is missing or the value is empty: order
```

What is the problem in this case?

Thanks at all

**UPDATE**

model:

```
class OrderMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :users
  has_one :movies
end



Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"6"}
```

The ID is the ID of the movie I search with the Movie.find params[:id]

```
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:249:in `require'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:21:in `order_params'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:9:in `payMovie'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/home/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"6"}
```

**UPDATE**

routes.rb

```
 resources :api_users, :as => :users

  get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
  post '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
  get '/' => 'startsites#index'
```

Comment: Could you show the request params or the controller log? And also you OrderMovie model?

Comment: Provide the stack trace. It doesn't look like the error has happened in the method `payMovie` (which is invalid Ruby identifier BTW).

Comment: why is it a invalid identifier?

Comment: stack trace added above. thanks

Comment: can you add the routes file, and the method `order_params` of the controller. this is a shot in the dark without those things, but it looks like this is a `show` route, and you're passing the value as `id` when it needs to be named `order`

Comment: Please post the `order_params` method.

Comment: don't have a function order_params. routes added above